# i cant fetch data after deployment in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment, axios, firebase-hosting

The app work perfectly locally. The error appears after i deploy it using firebase hosting. The code below is the component where i fetch the data from the api resource

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import{ useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux"
import { setProducts } from "../containers/redux/actions/productActions"
import ProductComponent from './ProductComponent';
import axios from 'axios';

function ProductList() {
    const products  = useSelector((state) => state);
    const dispatch  = useDispatch()

    const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState('');

    const fetchProducts = async ( searchValue) => {
     

        const response = await axios
        .get(`http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=${searchValue}&apikey=??????`)
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("Err", err);
        });
        if(response.data.Search){
            dispatch(setProducts(response.data.Search));
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchProducts(searchValue);
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    },[searchValue]);

    console.log("Products: " , products)
    
    return (
        <div className='home'>
            <div className='search-box'>
                    <input 
                    value={searchValue} onChange={(e) => setSearchValue(e.target.value)} 
                    type="text" 
                    placeholder="Search.." 
                    >        
                    </input>
            </div>
            <div className='products-list'>
            <ProductComponent /> 
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default ProductList
```

Error message appears on the console of the deployed app :

> ProductList.js:21 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data')

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>    if(response.data.Search){
>        dispatch(setProducts(response.data.Search));
>    }
> ```

Try to check your response first.
I think you may have to prove catch error here. Adding `else` statement in case of `response.data.Search` is undefined or use `response?.data.Search`

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers will block insecure requests (http) made from secure sites (https).

Change `http://www.omdbapi.com/` to `https://www.omdbapi.com/`